# difference between approach in join queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

First:

```
SELECT a.field, b.field
FROM a, b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Second:

```
SELECT a.field, b.field
FROM a INNER JOIN b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Are there any differences between these two approaches or they work the same way?

Comment: The final result will be the same. The question is if the execution will be the same. I guess that for this simple query the planner will be smart enough to make the same plan for both.

Comment: read the link that rs. posted

Comment: No difference except the possibility for errors and the difficulty in maintenance. Please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx

Comment: i've searched something like this, but i failed in the used keywords :( anyway thanks for the post, i'll take a look right now

Answer (score 0):

They yield the same results and perform the same, but I find the second method is far more legible in large queries, so it should always be used (although I format it differently)

I format like this:

```
SELECT
    a.field
   ,b.field
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```